# Restored/Wiped- Automatically enables Location Services like in LOST MODE?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, find-my-iphone

iPhone 4s with iOS 7.

Like in LOST MODE where the Location Services is automatically turned on eventhough it was OFF before you lost your iPhone, it will give it's location once the device connects to the internet - (already clarified, thank you so much!). Now the question is, Is it also the same when you restore/wiped the iPhone? Will it automatically enable the Location Services after being restored (as long as they will connect it online)?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that matters on iOS 7 is whether you have fine my phone enabled. Also, you can't turn off location services when you have find my phone active.

If so, you can't get iTunes or the device to erase itself unless you enter the password for iCloud account that is enrolled.

If you do factory erase it, it still won't re-activate unless the iCloud password is entered. So, to answer your question - location services is likely not re-enabled since the device lock prevents activation of the OS and opting in to location services before the wipe. It would either require access to the source code or servers from Apple to know if location is tracked in is case, but my intuition is no.

If you enable lost mode, that locks the device, but it still is traceable and can be located. Just as if you didn't enter lost mode.

If you erase the device, that removes the data and tracking ability once it connects to the Internet and receives the self-destruct message. It still displays the lost message, but you can't track it.

Comment: Yes I'm certain FMi is enabled. I just received a message from 'the thief' asking for my iCloud id and PW. I guess the custom message kicked in. He said he already erased/wiped the device the minute he got home. I think my password was saved but he can't see it as it should only show ******** right?

Comment: Anyone that recovers a lost iOS device can see the AppleID but not the password. I would change your iCloud password just to be safe, but they shouldn't be able to recover it in any way if you sent a lock message and got confirmation from Apple that the message was delivered.

Comment: There was no passcode and I turned off Location Services when I lost my iPhone. I didnt have the chance to set it in Lost Mode immediately bec I don't have the iCloud pw that was created by my friend for me and she said its saved (although will only show ****) in the device so Im guessing the thief can erase all settings and contents inside Settings/Privacy but since its tied up to my iCloud, I'll just let the Activation Lock do its job right?

Comment: The thief asked for your Apple ID and password. That's priceless.

Answer (score 0):

If the phone is wiped and a new iCloud account is used it is not possible to track a phone. In that kind of scenario it's best to report your IMEI to the police (along with your old iCloud account) and they will be able to track it down. Apple themselves can't track it for you with the IMEI as it will be breach of privacy.

Yes, in lost mode the location is enabled by default even when it will be turned off.

Comment: Police in our country will not bother to help with this type of problem :(

Comment: What if the iPhone is wiped/erased, will the Location Services be enabled too once they connect it online during setup? Im pretty sure my lost iPhone has IOS 7 and perhaps its preventing the thief from selling the device. Is it still trackable after being restored (since its still linked to my iCloud account)?